# write_verilog without instance names in Yosys

Tags: verilog, yosys, netlist

I am trying to use the write_verilog command to generate the nestlist without containing any cell names; rather, only with the verilog expressions. I try the following:

```
write_verilog -noexpr synth_001.v
```

But I still get the cell instances (names) in my generated netlist, which I **don't** want.

To clarify better, for example, in the generated synth_001.v, if I have

```
  XOR2X1 _207_ (
    .A(_006_),
    .B(_070_),
    .Y(_134_)   );
```

I would actually like the following:

```
assign _134_ = _006_ ^ _070_;
```

I have gone through the Yosys manual, even tried options available from google, like

```
rename -enumerate
```

but no luck yet.

Any tips/ideas will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `-noexpr` when writing verilog file.

```
write_verilog synth_001.v
```